# EE CMS Page Hierarchy url of submenu item shouldn't include url of it's parent

Tags: cms

I have a controller action "events/index/index" and a menu link to this page in the navigation menu. I added this menu link as a node with the url key "events". Now I want to move this menu link down one level (so it becomes visible in a dropdown), but the link breaks because it now links to /xyz/events instead of /events. Is there any way I can let Magento know it shouldn't prepend the parent url? Or is the only option to create a rewrite rule?

Comment: I think the best option in this case is to create a rewrite rule.

Comment: @Chris, that would work, but it really becomes chaotic and unmanageable in a large multi store / multi language environment.

Comment: @JakeA.Smith Of course this isn't suitable as a final solution for a large amount of routes. But the question involves just one route.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done here is effectively 'game' the URL key system by giving it a proper route to resolve prior to the CMS route being resolved.

The more proper way of handling this is to create the CMS link via layout xml within a layout file of the module which defines `events/index/index` route/controller/action.

Best of luck